# LLDB command to view human-readable values at specific memory addresses

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am running into an error in my iOS app, and the Stack Trace is not particularly illuminating. When I run the command **bt** on the (lldb) debugger console, it spits out a full back trace, like this:

```
    frame #0: 0x39de23e4 libsystem_c.dylib`__vfprintf + 28
    frame #1: 0x39df82c6 libsystem_c.dylib`__v2printf + 374
    frame #2: 0x39da723c libsystem_c.dylib`_vsnprintf + 348
    frame #3: 0x39da7b2c libsystem_c.dylib`vsnprintf_l + 32
    frame #4: 0x39da7b06 libsystem_c.dylib`snprintf_l + 22
    frame #5: 0x2f0a19d0 CoreFoundation`__CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8464
    frame #6: 0x2f010610 CoreFoundation`_CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 76
    frame #7: 0x2f9e8162 Foundation`-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 130
    frame #8: 0x2f9e8068 Foundation`+[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 60
  * frame #9: 0x002ce4e0 myApp`PFMD5HashFromData(data=0x18109b60) + 412 at PFHash.m:63
    frame #10: 0x002d4e42 myApp`-[PFJSONCacheItem initWithObject:](self=0x18109890, _cmd=0x31facc39, object=0x18138b90) + 286 at PFInternalUtils.m:286
    frame #11: 0x002d500a myApp`+[PFJSONCacheItem cacheFromObject:](self=0x006e00c8, _cmd=0x0058acb3, object=0x18138b90) + 74 at PFInternalUtils.m:300
    frame #12: 0x002e56d8 myApp`-[PFObject(self=0x18151620, _cmd=0x0058bdd1, object=0x18138b90, key=0x0064a2e8) checkForChangesToMutableContainer:forKey:]
```

#### My Question to the SO Community is this:

**Is it possible to use the LLDB debug console to view human-readable data at specific memory addresses**?

For example, the values that show up like this:

```
(self=0x18109890, _cmd=0x31facc39, object=0x18138b90)
```

Can I print out these values so I can see the data at these memory addresses?

**For example:** if I had the following value in memory:

```
// NSString @ memory address: 0x123456
NSString *example = @"exampleString";
```

What LLDB command could I use to see the human-readable value of `exampleString` at memory address `0x123456`?

Per the suggestions of others (thanks [Jim Ingham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2465073/jim-ingham)) and various internet searches, I have tried the following commands:

- `(lldb) expr *((MyObjectType *) 0x123456)`
- `(lldb) frame variable *object`
- `memory read -s1 -fu -c10000 0x123456 --force`

and a few others, but all these give me are even more memory addresses, or memory dumps that are not human-readable. What I am hoping to do, is read or print out the actual values that would have flowed through my program to see some clues about what could be going wrong.

### Update

I was finally able to print the values based on the advice I have received in this post so far. The reason I was getting more cryptic memory addresses was because I was trying to evaluate pre-complied binaries. When I ran the suggested commands against my own project code, everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  If you want raw memory dumps, try the `memory read` command.  If you have debug info for the type of the object, you can pass it to the `-t` option to `memory read` (this is more useful for arrays of objects.)

Or you can use the expression parser, something like:

```
(lldb) expr ((MyObjectType *) 0x18138b90)
```

If you are in frames with debug info, you can also use `frame variable` to view locals & arguments.  So for instance:

```
(lldb) frame variable *object
```

should show you the contents of `object`.

Comment: awesome. This looks very useful. I will test these ideas out and report back as soon as i get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: I made a few updates to my original post to clarify what I am looking for. Your contributions are helpful, but they give me more and more memory addresses or memory dumps that are just as hard to read as the backtrace. I haven't been able to use these commands you suggest to actually see the values of the items in memory (for example, the contents of an `NSString`, or the items held in an `NSDictionary`). Do you know how to do this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: can you please try this: expr ((MyObjectType *) 0x18138b90) (the same as Jim's idea but without a prefix star). For things like NSString and NSDictionary we should be definitely allow the kind of user-friendly inspection you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was able to get the values printing properly with a combination of Jim Ingram's advice, and @EnricoGranata Thanks to you both.